# Is there a way to plug the skipTrash option to oozie fs (HDFS) action while deleting files?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

As per oozie documentation, the supported commands for FS (HDFS) action are move , delete and mkdir. Is there a way to mention skipTrash option if I wanted to use the delete command.

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.4_Fs_HDFS_action

Answer (score 1):

The delete command of the FS action does not support using the user's trash directory. All paths deleted this way will be entirely deleted from the file system.

To delete files while using the user's trash directory a shell action could be created that calls `hdfs dfs -rm`. Ensure the trash is enabled by checking that `fs.trash.interval` is set greater than 0.

Comment: It's good to know that Oozie's `delete` will delete files directly instead of moving to Trash. I like this feature.